# Dialogflow Based on Duration

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

This might not be the best place to ask, but I was wondering if someone can help a new person out with fulfillment based on @sys.duration. For example, if someone responds to a prompt with 5 years or 10 months, they'll get differing replies based on those values.

I understand this may get tricky if someone replies "5 years" vs. a reply with "3 months..."

I've been using the inline editor and used the below based off of some demos and such I've found online:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

const TIME_INTENT = "Time";
const LENGTH_OF_TIME_ENTITY = "LengthOfTime";

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent(TIME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const length_of_service = conv.parameters[LENGTH_OF_TIME_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
    if (length_of_time > 5) {
        conv.ask("Response 1");
    } else {
        conv.ask("Response 2");
    }
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Can you update your question to make it clear what your question is?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're on the right track. I have a couple suggestions:

- I would change the name of `LENGTH_OF_TIME_ENTITY` to `LENGTH_OF_TIME_PARAMETER`. Entities are sort of like categories that user inputs fall under, which in your case would be @sys.duration. Parameters are the actual inputs.
- According to their docs the parameter you get from Dialogflow for a @sys.duration parameter is going to come in as an object that looks like `{"amount":10,"unit":"min"}`, so you'll want to make sure you're handling an object in that form. The [Dialogflow docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities) are a good reference when working with system entities.
- It looks like you're trying to do some sort of duration comparison. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations) is a frequently used library that can help with that. If you don't want to depend on a library, you'll need to roll your own solution to convert the different possible inputs you get from Dialogflow into the same unit so you can compare it to the duration cutoff you made to decide which response to use.

Putting that together, you'd do something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const moment = require('moment');

const TIME_INTENT = "Time";
const LENGTH_OF_TIME_ENTITY = "LengthOfTime";

const CUTOFF = moment.duration(5, "month");

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent(TIME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const input = conv.parameters[LENGTH_OF_TIME_ENTITY];
    const length_of_service = moment.duration(input.amount, input.unit);

    if (length_of_service.asSeconds() > CUTOFF.asSeconds()) {
        conv.ask("Response 1");
    } else {
        conv.ask("Response 2");
    }
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

You might need to do some conversion to get the unit strings Dialogflow uses to the form that Moment.js expects, but that should be pretty simple to do. I didn't thoroughly check the unit values for either, but something along these lines:

```
const toMomentUnit = (unit) => {
    switch(unit) {
        case "min":
            return "minutes";
        case "day":
            return "days";
        case "mo":
            return "months";
        case "year":
            return "years";
        default:
            throw new Error("Unrecognized unit");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this!
I think there is something in the unit conversion that I could use another set of eyes on. I keep getting my "response 2" even if it meets the condition for "response 1." Here's what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/r90muqpz/

Comment: Inside the handler you're feeding `input.toMomentUnit` into the `moment.duration` function. The property on the Dialogflow parameter is `unit`. You want to call the `toMomentUnit` function on that property. So change `const length_of_service = moment.duration(input.amount, input.toMomentUnit);` to `const length_of_service = moment.duration(input.amount, toMomentUnit(input.unit));`.

Comment: Hmm... then Dialogueflow kicks back a "input.toMomentUnit is not a function" error..  [http://jsfiddle.net/r90muqpz/](http://jsfiddle.net/r90muqpz/)

Comment: Forked your fiddle and left a comment pointing out the issue: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vwnsx2f8/)